# Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting on dyplr/tidyverse commands?

Tags: r, rstudio, syntax-highlighting

I am currently using dplyr on RStudio and I often find it difficult to read my code.

For example, in the following code block, all my dplyr functions have normal white highlighting:

[image: Example]

I would like things like summarise and mutate to appear pink or something like that, that way I can easily see what commands I use.

I have the same issue with ggplot which is also part of tidyverse. Sometimes the graphs and figures I make can get quite chunky and I have trouble following what I wrote.

Thanks

Comment: @Luuk Wow, I spent a lot of time googling the wrong stuff. Thank you so much!